# Access denied powershell moving files

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

```
ht = @{}
$o = new-object PSObject -property @{ 
    from = "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\scripturi copiere\BCC"
    to = "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\scripturi copiere\destinatiON" }
$ht.Add($o.from, $o) 

$o = new-object PSObject -property @{ 
    from = "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\scripturi copiere\BBB"
    to = "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\scripturi copiere\destinatiON" }
$ht.Add($o.from, $o) 

$o = new-object PSObject -property @{ 
    from = "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\scripturi copiere\BAA"
    to = "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\scripturi copiere\destinatiON" }
$ht.Add($o.from, $o) 

#  
foreach($server in $ht.keys  ) {

            copy-item $ht.Item($server).from -destination $ht.Item($server).to -Recurse ;

             }

sleep 5
$ht = $null
sleep 5

$ht = @{}
$o = new-object PSObject -property @{ 
    from = "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\scripturi copiere\destinatie\BCC"
    to = "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\scripturi copiere\destinatie\BCC\Processed" }
$ht.Add($o.from, $o) 

$o = new-object PSObject -property @{ 
    from = "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\scripturi copiere\destinatie\BBB"
    to = "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\scripturi copiere\destinatie\BBB\Processed" }
$ht.Add($o.from, $o) 

$o = new-object PSObject -property @{ 
    from = "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\scripturi copiere\destinatie\BAA"
    to = "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\scripturi copiere\destinatie\BAA\Processed" }
$ht.Add($o.from, $o) 

# the loop
foreach($server in $ht.keys  ) {

        gci |   Move-Item $ht.Item($server).from -Destination $ht.Item($server).to -Force   ;

             }
```

The last loop isn't working, I keep getting an error with access denied , after everything runs I have the last part to actually move from one place to another. 
Move-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\scripturi copiere\destinatie\BBB' is denied.
At line:47 char:13
+             Move-Item $ht.Item($server).from -Destination $ht.Item($s ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\nicola...\destination\BCC:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveDirectoryItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

I really can't wrap my head around this one, why do I keep getting the error. 
Also I have tried with the -Force option but from that ht of 3 items the first one doesn't go through .

This is the entire code.

Comment: are your `BCC` and `BAA` items working as expected? the error you are getting is rather specific ... it normally means just what it says ... the you are not allowed to access the item in question.

Comment: hello , yes the part of the copy process with the first ht works perfectly. it copies the files even if i runt it multiple times ( it does not duplicate) so that works perfectly. I just simply can't seem to find a way to move the files that were copied to another folder, any ideas? like other ways?

I even tried with dos commands , with robocopy works, the copy part, but it copies it does not move. I want it moved, and the move cmd from dos doesn't work either

Comment: you need to check the permissions on the source. the error means that _something_ is not as you expect it to be and is blocking your access.

Comment: The error doesn't match your code. Piping `gci` to `move-item` will trigger ´The input object cannot be bound to any parameters...´.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens, as the latter loop is trying to move the source directory itself. By adding the `-WhatIf` switch the behavior becomes clear. Like so,

```
foreach($server in $ht.keys  ) {
  Move-Item -whatif $ht.Item($server).from -Destination $ht.Item($server).to -Force   ;
}

# Line breaks added for readability
What if: Performing the operation "Move Directory" on target 
"Item: C:\temp\destinatie\BCC 
Destination: C:\temp\destinatie\BCC\Processed\BCC".
```

Consider fixing the `gci` part, like so,

```
foreach($server in $ht.keys  ) {
  gci $ht.Item($server).from |  % { Move-Item -whatif $_.FullName -Destination $ht.Item($server).to }
}

What if: Performing the operation "Move Directory" on target "Item: C:\temp\destinatie\BCC\Processed Destination: C:\temp\destinatie\BCC\Processed\Processed".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\temp\destinatie\BCC\1.txt Destination: C:\temp\destinatie\BCC\Processed\1.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\temp\destinatie\BCC\2.txt Destination: C:\temp\destinatie\BCC\Processed\2.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\temp\destinatie\BCC\3.txt Destination: C:\temp\destinatie\BCC\Processed\3.txt".
```

Much better. But wait, it's still trying to move the `Processed` and that we can't have. Let's exclude that one and try again.

```
foreach($server in $ht.keys  ) {
     gci $ht.Item($server).from -exclude "processed" |  % { Move-Item -whatif $_.FullName -Destination $ht.Item($server).to }
}

What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\temp\destinatie\BCC\1.txt Destination: C:\temp\destinatie\BCC\Processed\1.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\temp\destinatie\BCC\2.txt Destination: C:\temp\destinatie\BCC\Processed\2.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\temp\destinatie\BCC\3.txt Destination: C:\temp\destinatie\BCC\Processed\3.txt".
```

Comment: as I want to move only the contents? I basically have a folder with files and a subfolder. I want to move all the files in that other subfolder .
not sure how to do this.

Comment: it works perfectly, I only have some errors that are not terminating the code, like the folder already exists ( in case of multiple runs) but I guess that's not an issue.